# Dead Apple Watch -- security risk?

Tags: apple-watch, recycle

I have an Apple Watch 1st gen that does not power on anymore. I want to dispose of it. If I just recycle it (at a recycling center), can someone recover data off it?

Should I try to destroy it first (maybe by hitting it with a hammer like a hard drive)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to ensure that it is recycled securely, without resorting to any destructive practices that might hinder the recycling of the materials, is to hand it in to an Apple Store.

Apple will take any Apple branded material -- I've given them old batteries from laptops, USB cables, as well as broken iPads and phones.

You can be confident that Apple are not in the business of recovering any data from old Apple devices *(-- assuming you're already comfortable with using iCloud in the first place)*.

Comment: "You can be confident that Apple are not in the business of recovering any data" - can you? And what about three-letter agencies?

Comment: @TrangOul the lesser and more relevant assumption might be that giving Apple physical access to your dead watch will not make it any easier to access your data [on behalf of three-letter agencies or otherwise] than it was before, considering how reliant its function is on their cloud infrastructure

Comment: @Will: Yes, or to put it another way, you can be confident that Apple are not in the business of recovering any data from the dead watch, because if they want that data they can get it much more cheaply and easily by virtue of having full control of the software and hardware in the first place :)

Comment: @TrangOul If you're concerned about "three-letter agencies" reading your data, then your OpSec should involve not putting that data on an Apple Watch in the first place.

Comment: "You can be confident that Apple are not in the business of recovering any data" What about the Apple Store owner, though? Note that there is [research](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/11/half-of-computer-repairs-result-in-snooping-of-sensitive-data-study-finds/) suggesting (with a small sample size) that computer repair stores do access their customers' data.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Those are independent repair shops, dealing with Windows 10 laptops; not Apple Stores. As said, Apple hardware has built-in encryption at the hardware level, so the drones in the shop are not going to be capable of hacking in; and if Apple was doing it at an institutional level, they would have easier methods.

Comment: @benwiggy (1) Yes, those were not Apple stores, but I see no reason to think Apple stores are above this practice. (2) We don't know what the problem is; maybe it is enough to change the internal battery to be able to turn on the watch. This is something an Apple store drone can do, right? And I know very little about Apple Watches, but from what I can read on the internet it is possible that no passcode is set, and in this case the watch will boot and happily reveal private data.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Apple Store staff are largely following set procedures and have no room for 'initiative'. You can even wipe your Watch remotely using "Find My"; so as soon as it's working.

Comment: Apple and more importantly, Apple employees are **not** the ones handling the recycling.  It’s going to a 3rd party contractor for disposal:  https://abcnews.go.com/Business/recycled-iphones-apple-products/story?id=37872881

Comment: An Apple device with no passcode set should be considered completely unsecured. Without a passcode, anyone stealing your device can do anything they want. At that point asking about recycling is pointless. It's like securing the windows in your home when your front door is wide open and a sign "please enter and help yourself" outside.

Answer (score 8):

The storage in the Apple Watch is encrypted and the device secured with secure boot and activation lock so disposing of it should not be a security risk.

[System Security for watchOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/system-security-for-watchos-secc7d85209d/web)

That said, there’s still no substitute for ensuring data destruction than physically destroying it with a hammer,  if you have the technical ability, I’d disassemble it and sell it for parts and only destroy the logic board.

The lithium battery inside is a fire hazard if you crush the case, so have a proper company recycle it is strongly advised.

Answer (score -2):

I **suspect** NSA or folks with equivalent resources could get the data, but I doubt those folks would be collecting discarded Apple watches from landfills or recycling centers.

Nevertheless, I'd put it in a hot fire or grind it up.  But I'm a bit OCD about such things.  If you choose the hammer and think NSA has you on a watchlist, make sure there are no intact IC chips.  :-)

Comment: The watch has a small non-removable lithium battery inside - a fire is probably a bad idea.

Comment: True, in general.  Depends on whether the fire is contained and how.  My fires are in an over with thick cast iron walls.  But smashing thouroughly with a hammer is probably just as good.  Or grinding it.

Comment: -1 for the fire. Totally unnecessary health risk for the average Joe/Jane, and not great for the environment either.