# Make a stickdrive from Apple Watch NAND chip?

Tags: apple-watch, logicboard

I recently asked a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462153/dead-apple-watch-security-risk) about a dead Apple Watch 1st generation and whether I could dispose of it without worrying about my data being stolen. I got several responses. One in particular stood out to me, from Allan:

> ...there’s still no substitute for ensuring data destruction than physically destroying it with a hammer, if you have the technical ability, I’d disassemble it and sell it for parts and only destroy the logic board.

Could I use the logic board for anything useful? I saw a video on YouTube where someone turned the NAND flash chip on an old iPhone into a USB flash drive. I know it would be small, but could I do it with this? The video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqWLSK2lgsI).

Comment: That would be a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ … unless you wanted to make an attractive key-fob, in which case it would be https://crafts.stackexchange.com/ ;) Check their question guidelines first.

Comment: Unless you can backwards engineer the [S7 CPU](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Apple-S7-Processor-Benchmarks-and-Specs.575945.0.html), the answer is nothing.  It’s an integrated “package” that includes everything including the storage